# How to work with money values in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Now I store `balance` field in MySQL like `decimial(15, 2)`. And in PHP I use the [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.bc.php) library for operations:

`bccomp($currentBalance, 100.15, 2)` - for check if user have enough money.
`bcadd($currentBalance, 100)` - for increase user balance.

And etc.

This is working correctly, but BCMath doc says:

> Passing values of type float to a BCMath function which expects a
>   string as operand may not have the desired effect due to the way PHP
>   converts float values to string, namely that the string may be in
>   exponential notation (what is not supported by BCMath), and that the
>   decimal separator is locale dependend (while BCMath always expects a
>   decimal point).

So I want to avoid surprises. What is the right way to deal with money?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As integers.  Convert 100.15 to 10015 and keep track of the currency so you know how many decimal places to apply when displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Follow http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php

I think you should pass params as string. In your case, maybe bccomp("$currentBalance", "100.15", 2) -> Not yet test.

Comment: there are still converting floats to strings.